# Problem with letter "\dj" in small-caps font

Tags: small-caps

The letter `\dj` has its bar placed too high when used in lower case small caps, e.g.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\textsc{\dj}
\end{document}
```

What do I need to add to the preamble in order to correct this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 12):

For Croatian (and most continental European languages) it's recommended to use T1 encoded fonts; if you load also the `inputenc` package (and save your documents in UTF-8 encoding) you're also allowed to input characters with diacritics directly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\title{A paper}
\author{Ivica Smolić}
\maketitle

\textsc{\dj} \textsc{đ}
\end{document}
```

[image]